# 42S22 1054 Unknown column in where clause

Tags: mysql, json

Using JSON I am returning from database.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'id'
FROM avail
WHERE start >='$dayOfEvent' AND start < DATE_ADD('$dayOfEvent', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND title = '$doctorName'
AND backgroundColor = 'red'
```

Passed in is 'Curly' for the doctor name and '2015-11-30' for the date.

```
"Array([0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'Curly' in 'where clause')1"
```

The problem is, the column isn't called curly, it is 'title'

I've ran this in mysql and it works just fine!

Comment: Post the sql that gets executed and produces the above error.

Comment: Use backticks ` for column names

Comment: @maxhb I have, 'curly' and '2015-11-30' passed in

Comment: @davidstrachan I have added the back ticks into the column names within the where clause, and it doesn't make any difference. Still recieving the same error